# what is wrong with this C program, file reading?

Tags: c, file

I was writing a C program, In which i Have to read a large file in to blocks (16 characters per block). For that I have written the following code.

```
while(fgets(temp2,16,fp)!=NULL)
{
    printf("\n%d:%s, len = %d", cnt++, temp2, strlen(temp2));
}
```

But its reading only 15 characters. What is wrong with this? what should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is wrong with this?

Nothing.  It's doing what you told it.  It will read up to 15 characters, unless it encounters newline or end-of-file, and then null-terminate the byte just after the last one written.

> what should i do?

Read the [reference for `fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), which states:

> `char *fgets( char *str, int count, FILE *stream );`
>
> Reads at most `count - 1` characters from the given file stream and stores them in str. The produced character string is always null-terminated. Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.

What you probably wanted to use was `fread`, not `fgets`, since your problem talks about reading blocks of characters rather than newline-delimited strings.

- [Reference for `fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread)

Comment: God I hate it when the computer keeps doing exactly what I've told it to do, but doing it wrong....Ho hmm....

Comment: It's worse when it almost always does what I _think_ I told it, and only after hours of troubleshooting do I discover it was doing what I _actually_ told it... and it only seemed to do what I _thought_ it did because of undefined behaviour ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation of [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). It is reading a *line*.

If your file is binary (so open it with  `fopen("/path/to/file","rb")`) and you care about fixed size blocks use [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).